# "if" statements of bash under mac os

Tags: macos, bash

If there some difference between the bash of Mac OS and other linuxs'? 
I wrote a simple bash script named "test.sh" like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
MYVAR=abc
if [ $MYVAR = abc ]; then
echo "ok"
fi
```

When I run it in terminal, some error occurs:

```
./test.sh: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `then'
./test.sh: line 3: `if[ $MYVAR = abc ]; then'
```

then I delete the character ";" before "then" and run the script again, some infos occurs:

```
./test.sh: line 3: if[ abc = abc ]: command not found
ok
./test.sh: line 5: syntax error near unexpected token `fi'
./test.sh: line 5: `fi'
```

Could someone tell me what's wrong with my script?

Comment: The lesson here is not to re-type your code for us to see. Cut and paste, the same way you pasted your error messages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider putting spaces into your file the way you put it in your example (`if [`).

Answer (score 2):

`[` is a command (same as `test`). It must be separated by spaces on both sides.